# Do I need the Pantone Solid Coated Guide if I have Color Bridge Coated Guide?

Tags: color, cmyk, pantone

I need a Solid Coated Pantone Guide. If I buy the Coated Color Bridge, does that have all the solid swatches (PMS) in addition to the CMYK equivalent?

i.e. Would it be redundant to buy the regular Solid Coated book if I had the Coated Color Bridge guide.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes it would be redundant.**

The Color Bridge Guide has 2 swatches for every color - the Pantone color, then next to it the CMYK equivalent. There would be little point in also having the solid formula guide.

[image]

Okay, not *totally* redundant. Sometimes having the full swatch of the Pantone color can be handy, but it won't be any different than the color in the Color Bridge guide. If cost is a factor, you can safely go with the Color Bridge Guide alone.

Comment: Ok cool. So long as it is printed as the solid PMS in the Bridge I think I'll just go with the Bridge for now. My worry was that it was somehow not identical to the regular solid coated guide. Thanks again!

Comment: Nope the Pantones will be identical. That is the entire point of them :) Color Bridge alone will serve you well.

Comment: Excellent. Hopefully my color nightmares will dissipate when UPS shows up with my new guides :) (I've been ordering chip pages individually for jobs... haha!)