# Swatch books by Pantone: CMYK Color guide or Color Bridge guide?

Tags: pantone, color-spaces

I would like to buy a swatch book by Pantone - I mostly work with CMYK colors and was thinking of getting the standard CMYK Color guide when, I realised that the Bridge guide also had CMYK swatches as well as Pantone spot color swatches, which makes me wonder the following:

1. Does the Color Bridge guide have all the CMYK swatches included in the CMYK Color guide, as well as the Pantone swatches?
2. In case I might work more with spot colors in the future, if I get the Color Bridge guide, can I use it for my current CMYK print projects or is it less handy to use?
3. For those who have the CMYK Color guide, is it complete? Somehow 2,868 CMYK colors does not seem like a lot...

If I had unlimited budget, I would get both sets but as it's not an option now I am trying to get the best I can.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sharlott.

---

Note: I have updated my question to make it more understandable since it was identified as redundant to this [one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56154/do-i-need-the-pantone-solid-coated-guide-if-i-have-color-bridge-coated-guide). I think they are comparing the [Formula Guide](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56154/do-i-need-the-pantone-solid-coated-guide-if-i-have-color-bridge-coated-guide) and the [Bridge guide](http://www.pantone.com/color-bridge-coated-uncoated), when I am trying to decide between the standard [CMYK guide](http://www.pantone.com/cmyk-coated-uncoated) and the [Bridge guide](http://www.pantone.com/color-bridge-coated-uncoated) .  I hope it's easier to understand now :-)

Comment: I am surprised no one has any input on this! Maybe someone owns the CMYK Color guide and would be able to tell me how they like it? Do they feel it is pretty much complete or do they feel they are missing colors? TIA

Comment: possible duplicate http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56154/do-i-need-the-pantone-solid-coated-guide-if-i-have-color-bridge-coated-guide

Comment: @hsawires: Thank you for reading my question! I have updated it now - I think Michelle was comparing Formula versus Bridge - I am looking at CMYK Color versus Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used or seen the BRIDGE set, but from what I can tell by reading the online description, it doesn't contain all the CMYK swatches from that set. What it does contain is CMYK simulations of the Pantone colors.

> The PANTONE PLUS SERIES COLOR BRIDGE Set provides process colour simulations of all solid PANTONE Colours

From the online specifications, the CMYK set includes:

> 2,868 process CMYK colours

While the BRIDGE set includes:

> all 1,755 PANTONE Solid Colours

And also includes:

> sRGB and HTML values for solid colours

So unless you do or are planning on working from Pantone colors I would stick to the CMYK set.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question Cai Morris. I think you are right, the CMYK guide is probably what suits my current needs best... I was trying to minimize my long term costs but it's probably silly!

Comment: Its not silly at all. The PANTONE guides aren't cheap!